# Extracting and automating xkeycaps configuration

Tags: keyboard-layout, mac, xmodmap

This is my procedure every time I start my computer:

```
xkeycaps -kbd mac
```

I then swap the downarrow and left shift keys, which in fact switches the Left-Command and Left-Option on my Mac keyboard.

Try as I may, I can't figure out how to automate this. I've tried using its xmodmap export feature, I've tried writing xmodmap files myself, but nothing has any effect.

I'm looking for a way to make this key exchange from the CLI so I can put it in a script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xmodmap`.

```
xmodmap -pke > current.config
```

saves your current keyboard config to the file `current.config`. You can open this file in an editor and make your changes. You can read the config with the command

```
xmodmap current.config
```

You can also this command in any script.

Comment: Perhaps more usefully, `xmodmap -pke >oldmap`, then do the `xkeycaps` thing, then `xmodmap -pke | diff oldmap -` to see what changed. `-pke` won't catch modifier map changes, though, and there's no `-pme` equivalent so that part will have to be translated manually.

Comment: I did this procedure. It left a sensible diff between the new and old configs. However, running xmodmap on the new config (after a reboot) had no effect.